# Protractor tests won't run on Angular 4 site without waitForAngularEnabled(false)

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a website under test which is built with Angular 4.

My protractor tests won't run on them unless I specify `waitForAngularEnabled(false)` or `ignoreSynchronization = true`.

I have verified with the developer and the tech lead that the site is fully Angular.

Developer said that even though the site is developed with Angular, to the browser it is sent as a 'bundle'. (I am not sure what it means in dev terms).

**Below is my spec file:**

```
 describe('****** Home Page Tests', function() {
        var frontpage = require("./Front_page.js");

        beforeEach(function() {
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)
            browser.get('mytesturl',50000);
            frontpage.Front_page_link.click()

        })

        it('Should go to **** page', function(){

            frontpage.Journey_button.click()
            browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
                expect(url).toContain('journey/get-started')
            })
        })

    });
```

**Below is my config file:**

```
    var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');


exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
    //framework: 'jasmine2',

    specs : [ 'spec.js' ],

    onPrepare : function() {

        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath : 'target/screenshots'
        }));
    },

    allScriptsTimeout : 50000,


    jasmineNodeOpts : {
        showColors : true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval : 100000,
        isVerbose : true
    }

};
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 50 seconds
```

Comment: Share your code and config to give better view on the issue

Comment: When you say will not run is it hanging or failing with an error?

Comment: I have updated my original post with the spec and config file code snippets.

Comment: @Arshad when the dev says angular is sent as a bundle he may mean that the site is [manually bootstrapped](https://www.protractortest.org/#/system-setup), could you check that out and see if it is the case?

Comment: I haven't really taken the time to dig in and figure out why but I've noticed this happening with the app I'm currently working on. The app is bundled using webpack. It may be something similar in your situation that is causing this. Seems that if the code is minified it doesn't want to work without setting `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`.  Of course, there is a good possibility I'm just doing it wrong but I've been too busy lately to explore what the real issue is. Anyhow, ask if they are using webpack, or some other similar bundling tool. My guess is that's why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Any action on an element selected by `By.css` or `$` or `$$` or whatever causes protractor to first wait for angular to stabilize by calling the `waitForAngular` function. What does it mean to 'wait for angular to stabilize'?

This function is waiting for all pending http-queries and all unfinished timeouts and doesn't allow the script to proceed further if they are found.

So basically most of the time you can just user `browser.sleep(3000)` most of the times, because the majority of timeouts happen in animations and such, and most of http-queries will be finished after 3 seconds.

However sometimes the timeouts will not be finished in 3 seconds: such as in cases of long polling or some features implementd using super-long timeouts. In our application we had the auto-logout feature implemented. After login, the service would check the expiration date of the JWT token and wait for (ExpirationDate-CurrentDate) before logging the user out. As you can imagine, it was a huge timeout, 36-hours timeout! After we removed it, everything worked like a charm.

Don't do that, implement these features differently. Search for all occurences of `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `timeout`, `interval` in your code and deal with them.

Comment: When you say `and deal with them` what was the alternative in your situation with the logout? What did you replace it with after you removed it?

Answer (score -1):

Try with https://angular.io/
by setting browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true).
If it is working you have configured things properly.

Comment: It is working for the above site. Is it AngularJS or Angular4?